# Is there a way to separate an object and keep the same "look"

Tags: mesh

I want to make a separate object from one of the panels, it is an imported OBJ (I'm guessing this is the problem) but when i do this using P > selection the smoothness/roundness has been removed. I would like to know if there's a way to make the panel a separate object but keep it the way it is. [image]

[image]

Comment: I have just tried and for me it does keep the smooth groups. Do you do something else after separating, like joining the new object?

Comment: thanks for the reply, no that's literally the before and after shot. so edit mode, select panel, p selection, back to object mode to check

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need this addon

> https://github.com/fedackb/yavne

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail to the answer. What does the proposed addon do? What is the relevant information on the video?

Comment: tried the addon and used the transfer shader option. not sure if this was the intention of the answer but looking at the documentation it seemed the most relevant, please advise if incorrect. but it didn't have the desired effect, results shown in the [link](http://imgur.com/a/FElU4)